# Rewriting multiple if statements

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am looking for best practice to write multiple if statements and making code more reusable. these are my if statements that i wuld like to change

```
    public DataSet getOrganizationDataSet(string organizationType, string 
    name, string state, string city, string county, string zip)
    {
        string search = "";

        if (organizationType != "")
        {
            search = search + "&type=" + organizationType;
        }
        if (name != "")
        {
            search += "&name=" + name;
        }
        if (city != "")
        {
            search = search + "&town=" + city;
        }
        if (zip != "")
        {
            search = search + "&zip=" + zip;
        }
        if (county != "")
        {
            search = search + "&county=" + county;
        }
        if (state != "")
        {
            search = search + "&state=" + state;
        }
}
```

i am thinking about writing code like this to make it more readable:

```
 public DataSet getOrgDataSet(string type, string name, string state, 
 string city, string county, string zip)
    {
        string search = "";

        if ((type ?? state ?? name ?? city ?? county ?? zip) != "") {

            search += "&type=" + type;
            search += "&name=" + name;
            search += "&town=" + city;
            search += "&county=" + county;
            search += "&zip=" + zip;
            search +=  "&state=" + state;

     }
```

I would like to know your opinion on this and best practices. 
Thanks in advance, and sorry for novice question, i am still learning c#

Comment: Those aren't equivalent implementations. You're going to end up with a lot of empty &(param)= in the second one.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I think it should go onto the code review site. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Helper methods are among the most basic means of code reuse. Make a helper method that appends to your query conditionally, like this:

```
private static void AppendSearch(StringBuilder search, string name, string value) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
        search.Append($"&{name}={value}");
    }
}
```

Now you can call this method repeatedly for each individual item to construct your search string:

```
var search = new StringBuilder();
AppendSearch(search, "name", name);
AppendSearch(search, "town", town);
AppendSearch(search, "zip", zip);
...
var searchString = search.ToString();
```

**Note:** The implementation uses C# 6 syntax for string interpolation. Use `AppendFormat` method if you are using an earlier version of the language:

```
search.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", name, value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do a private method in your class :

```
private string AddProperty(String property, String value)
{
    if (value != "")
    {
        return $"&{propertie}={value}";
    }
    return "";
}
```

Then, you can use it like this :

```
public DataSet getOrgDataSet(string type, string name, string state, string city, string county, string zip)
{
    string search = "";

    search += AddProperty("type", type);
    search += AddProperty("name", name);
    search += AddProperty("town", city);
    search += AddProperty("county", county);
    search += AddProperty("zip", zip);
    search += AddProperty("state", state);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't know if it is best practice (and asking for that makes your question off-topic, btw), but this is what I do most of the time:

```
string search =
    String
        .Join("", new[]
        {
            new { key= "type", value = organizationType },
            new { key= "name", value = name },
            new { key= "town", value = city },
            new { key= "zip", value = zip },
            new { key= "county", value = county },
            new { key= "state", value = state },
        }
        .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.value))
        .Select(x => $"&{x.key}={x.value}"));
```

Comment: This is miles from me, i dont even know how to implement this or i have great understanding of lambdas in the bottom. Thx for help, i hope that one day i wil get there :)

Comment: @VasilijZ - At least you know what a lambda is. That's a good start. You'll get there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding the possible values in the implementation, move those details to the caller and allow any number of parameters:

```
public DataSet getOrganizationDataSet(params KeyValuePair<string, string>[] filters)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var filter in filters)
    {
        //c# 6 / VS2015+
        builder.Append($"&{filter.Key}={filter.Value}");
        // VS2013 and lower
        builder.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", filter.Key, filter.Value);
    }

    string search = builder.ToString();
}
```

This way, if the names of the filters change, you don't have to change `getOrganizationDataSet`. You could call this method like:

```
var dataSet = getOrganizationDataSet(
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("city", city),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("type", type),
    // ... etc
);
```

Comment: When i try to implement this i have an error that not all code returns a value in getOrganizationDataSet.

Comment: @VasilijZ Well, you didn't add any code to your question that actually creates and returns a dataset

Answer (score -1):

The best practice would be to create `OrganizationFilter` model, with `GetSearchString` method, which uses dasblinkenlight answer's proposed private method:

```
public class OrganizationFilter
{
    public string OrganizationType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; } 
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    public string GetSearchString()
}
```

Then, you will have your method rewritten like this:

```
public DataSet getOrganizationDataSet(OrganizationFilter filter)
{
    string search = filter.GetSearchString();
    //...
}
```